# How find a length of each dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where each table cell is a dropdown menu. For each menu there is a different number of options in it (based on mysql query).
Is there any way I can check a number of options for each individual dropdown menu? Overall goal is to disable those menus where the number is <= 0.

Most of the examples uses an id of HTML element. I don't have an id for each dropdown menu, because depending on some database values each time page can have different number of the menus. They all belong to same class. Right now I am just trying to see if I finally can get a correct number, but it looks that I get a total number of all options on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".my_menu").each(check_length);
});
```

first try:

```
function check_length() {
  var sl_size = $("select > option").length;
  console.log("number: " + sl_size);
}
```

second try:

```
function check_length() {
  var sl_size = $(this).children.length;
  console.log("number: " + sl_size);
 }
```

third try:

```
function check_length() {
  var sl_size = $(this).length;
  console.log("number: " + sl_size);
 }
```

and so forth and so on... Any help will be highly appreciated.

---

Code snippet as it was asked:

```
for ($q=1; $q<= 4; $q++) { // it loops 4 times for four columns I need
 echo "<td>";
 echo "<select class='my_menu' >";
 echo "<option value=''>  </option>"; // just an empty option for a better look of the page

 foreach($array as $ar) { // compares values of array with some other variables
   if($ar["station"] == $my_station && $ar["experience"] >= 3) {
   echo "<option value='".$ar["worker"]."'>".$ar["worker"]."</option>";
   } // end of if statement
   else { echo ""; }
 } // end of foreach loop
 echo "</select></td>";
}
```

The whole code is too big to show. Basically every time the values are being compared - it generates a different list of names. And everything works great. I want to know if there is any chance to get a total number of items for each list? I do not see an opportunity to do it with PHP or MySQL with this layout, but hope to find a solution with jQuery. If solution doesn't exist, it is fine.

Comment: may you add a HTML fragment for a dropdown menu?

Comment: It would also help to see the PHP code that _generates_ those dropdowns based on the query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, here is demo https://jsbin.com/virepis/edit?html,js,console,output

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".table select").each(function(){
    if($('option', this).length <= 0) {
      $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks to @Ashutosh, i am using his html

Comment: Bingo! It all was about syntax. It works perfectly fine. I just had to change a compared number to 1, because I have an extra blank select option for each dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

Your **check_length** takes two arguments:

1. idx: index of current element inside each
2. ele: current element

For more details you may take a look to [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Inside your iteration function you need to find the select elements and for each one you can [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) (build an array) of lengths:

```js
function check_length(idx, ele) {
    var sl_size = $(ele).find("select").map(function(idx, ele) {
        return ele.options.length;
    }).get();
    console.log("number: " + sl_size);
}
$(".my_menu").each(check_length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="my_menu">
    <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it didn't work for me.  The return value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have asked, have tried to simulate. Try it. It first finds the table, then each td, then each select and then count the options in that select. Thnx

```js
$('.table').find('td').each(function() {
    var optionCount =0;
    $(this).find('.selectpicker option').each(function() {
      ++optionCount;
    });
    console.log("optionCount:"+optionCount);
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table class="table">
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><select class="selectpicker">
              <option>row 1 op 1</option>
            </select></td>
      <td><select class="selectpicker">
              <option>row 1 op 1</option>
              <option>row 1 op 2</option>
            </select></td>
      <td>@<select class="selectpicker">
              <option>row 1 op 1</option>
              <option>row 1 op 2</option>
              <option>row 1 op 3</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td><select class="selectpicker">
              <option>row 2 op 1</option>
              <option>row 2 op 2</option>
              <option>row 2 op 3</option>
              <option>row 2 op 4</option>
            </select></td>
      <td><select class="selectpicker">
              <option>row 2 op 1</option>
              <option>row 2 op 2</option>
              <option>row 2 op 3</option>
              <option>row 2 op 4</option>
              <option>row 2 op 5</option>
            </select></td>
      <td>@<select class="selectpicker">
              <option>row 2 op 1</option>
              <option>row 2 op 2</option>
              <option>row 2 op 3</option>
              <option>row 2 op 4</option>
              <option>row 2 op 5</option>
              <option>row 2 op 6</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    
   
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I do appreciate your time, but unfortunately your advise didn't work for me either.  The value stays a zero. I will keep reading.